# Instructions on how to install IDES in a laptop

Tags: sap-erp

Does anyone know where I can find detail instructions on how to install the SAP IDES in a laptop? I am trying to find how to install in Linux and in a free DB. Or the best will be to find the VM file because the installation will be in a VM.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Download latest Software Provisioning Manager (SPM) and run it. You can select db and app (IDES). It will guiding you for needed installation files and configuration. You need authorized user for downloading these software.